# Check if a list is a subset of another with no repititions python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have a large list (~200,000 elements) and another list of size 1-9. I need to find the longest arrangement of the small list in the large list. So I need to find whether the small list is a subset of the large list, with no repetitions (i.e. is [a,a] a subset of [a,b,c] should return False). Is there a way to do this?

I have tried .issubset but this returns true for duplicates. I have also tried checking through each permutation of the small list but this is too slow.

Comment: So the order does not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (as suggested by your use of set), Python provides it's own multiset implementation through [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), so use it:

```
from collections import Counter

short = ['a','a']
large =  ['a','b','c']

short_counts = Counter(short)
large_counts = Counter(large)

print(all(value <= large_counts.get(key, 0) for key, value in short_counts.items()))
```

**Output**

```
False
```

Putting all in a function and adding some examples we get:

```
def sub_multi_set(sh, la):
    short_counts = Counter(sh)
    large_counts = Counter(la)
    return all(value <= large_counts.get(key, 0) for key, value in short_counts.items())


print(sub_multi_set(['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(sub_multi_set(['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(sub_multi_set(['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']))
print(sub_multi_set(['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(sub_multi_set(['d', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

**Output**

```
False
True
True
True
False
```